# Problemas al modificar una tabla en MySQL desde NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un programa que maneje MySQL desde netbeans, me encuentro haciendo operaciones basicas, cómo guardar, modificar y eliminar.

```
String sql = "UPDATE materias SET codigo=?, descripcion=?, creditos=? WHERE codigo ="+model_i.getMts_Codigo();
```

Este es el codigo que uso para que se modifique la columna que el usuario pida, utilizo el codigo para hacerle referencia y que sucedan los cambios.

Todo funciona bien si en dicho codigo se digitan numeros, pero al momendo de agregar letras a este ocurre el siguiente problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los datos de la base de datos están así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según lo entiendo, SQL no detecta cuando quiero realizar la busqueda por medio de Strings, pues como mencioné, con numero va de maravilla.

Me gustaría saber si existe algún modo de que busque y modifique con exito al ingresar una palabra, no se si halla que agregar algo al codigo o ajustar los parametros de la tabla.

(Por cierto, estos son los parametros actuales que le asigné)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-El ID no lo estoy utilizando, pues necesito es buscar con el codigo.

Espero haberme hecho entender, y si no, estaré pendiente para responder por si alguien desea ayudarme :c

Comment: el código es varchar, intenta colocarlo entre comillas

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando marcadores (`?`) para todos los campos excepto para el que se usa en el `WHERE`.

Eso provoca que, además de que tu código falle cuando el contenido sea texto, tu código pueda sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

La forma de corregirlo sería usar marcadores para TODO:

```
String sql = """
    UPDATE materias
    SET codigo=?, descripcion=?, creditos=?
    WHERE codigo=?
""";
```

En ese caso tendrías que agregar una línea adicional a la consulta (asumiendo que tu consulta preparada está almacenada en `consulta`):

```
consulta.setString(4, model_i.getMts_Codigo());
```

Aunque lo más lógico sería quitar del `SET` la asignación del campo `codigo`, ya que éste va a ser el que se está buscando:

```
String sql = """
    UPDATE materias
    SET descripcion=?, creditos=?
    WHERE codigo=?
""";
```

Tras hacer esta modificación debes hacer cambios en los `setString()` para ajustar los índices.